# Cross origin policy issues when logging in via Google OAuth2 in latest version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth

On my site, we create a popup window which that gets redirected to Google authorization, with a RedirectUri back to my site after login specified. In the main window, we check the state of the popup window to determine whether or not a user has already logged in so that we can close this popup window.

Normally, once the user has logged in and the popup has been redirected back to my site, we can access the popup window in the main window. However, starting with the latest version of Chrome (v. 63.0.3239.132), we'll get the following error:

```
DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

This seems related to [this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796912), however we aren't calling window.open from an iframe (it gets called from the main site). 63.0.3239.132 was also supposed to introduce a fix for this issue.

I don't always repro this issue: if a user is already logged into their Google account, the main window can access the popup window once the popup gets redirected back to my site. Also, after the initial redirect to Google authorization (to the account selector page), I can navigate the popup window back to my site, at which point the main window will be able to access the popup window once more.

This issue also don't repro in earlier versions of Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet. Also not sure if there's a better avenue for getting help re: this issue

Comment: We're also facing a similar issue. We can't access to the window.opener anymore from the popup window which handles the oauth callback

Comment: @WarrenZhang It happens here as well. I actually spent around 7 hours to understand it is a bug on chrome and it works with Firefox. Another thing I noticed which can be a clue for how to identify the problem is that if I try it with facebook oauth callback, I CAN access the popup location property after the redirection to callback. I also noticied that if I stop on a breakpoint in the main window, the facebook popup freezes and I can't enter input (such as email and password) and the google popup does not freeze at all. Only difference I found that makes one work and one to not

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?? I am also experiencing the same issue in google OAuth2.

Comment: @AnIshA I haven't tried Raith sholution yet but I think it is a nice solution and that it would work. I will update once I verify it

Answer (score 1):

I can't fix your problem but I can suggest an alternative way to go about what you are doing.

Rather than accessing the popup window directly from your main page, or the main page from your popup (window.opener), have you considered communicating between these pages (which are both served from your app) by using the browser's `sessionStorage`?

Your pages/windows will share sessionStorage so one or both can hook into the `window.onstorage` event to watch for changes made by the other.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onstorage

I realise that this will require some redevelopment and therefore isn't strictly an answer to your problem, but I hope it is still a useful suggestion.